# Selecting max value from point table w. multiple repeated operators in query

Tags: qgis, point, query

How can I generate a query for the following issue?

I have a table that has companies and values they have published to market. I am trying to display the highest value on a map, but unfortunately they have the same x,u therefore get many overlapping points and labels. I would like to query the highest value by operator/company if possible

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table, with some example of duplicate companies?

Comment: What is x,u? Should be `(x,y)` or sth. alike?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Virtual Layer.

I have two fields with duplicate values:

**family** and **genus**. I want to select the distinct family & genus
combination on each location with the highest **month** (an integer column) value:

```
select family, genus, month, geometry
from pointlayer
group by X(geometry), Y(geometry)
order by month desc
```

[image]